# Formula for heat wire Kanthal or NiCr Watt consume?

Tags: resistance, watts, thermal, gauge

The input voltage is 220v in single phase. 
How many watt consumed for Kanthal A1 (heat wire) AWG18 for 30m at 1400 degree Celcius ?
How many If I use NiCr 60 or 80 with AWG18 ?

Does anybody know the formula ? Does your formula apply for NiChrome wire ?

I read the following below and confused : 
[Formula between wire size and current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100030/formula-between-wire-size-and-current) 
[1000 watts, 220 volt, 52" length, Coiled Nichrome wire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/142077/1000-watts-220-volt-52-length-coiled-nichrome-wire)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWG 18 has a nominal diameter of 1.016mm, and a cross section of 0.8107mm^2. The resistivity of Kanthal A1 is 1,45Ω-mm^2/m at 20 celcius. So the total resistance of 30m will be 53.65Ω at 20 degr.

The temperature factor of resistivity Ct at 1,400 degr. is given by the manufactures as 1.05 so the resistance at this temeprature will be 56.34Ω. So the consumed power will be P=220^2/56.34 or about 860W.

1400 degrees is the maximum contius temperature that you can use A1. As for V80 this temperature is the melting point, so you can not use for the specific application. You can check now by yourself the use of Nichr 60 alloy.

Comment: Yes, That's Correct that the NiCr 80 or 60 can not stand for 1400 Celcius. Can you tell he how to count the resistance for 1.45Ω-mm^2/m to become 13,41Ω at 20 degr ?

Comment: @ Sidhi Ciang R=ρxL/A. ρ is the resistivity of the alloy in Ω-mm^2/m and it is given by the manufcturer under physical properties usually at 20 degr. Celc.

Comment: And also how to count  P=220^2/14.o84 to become 4,37kW ? My calculation is about 3.44 KW... did I miss something ? (P=V^2/R)

Comment: Correct....You didn't miss asomething. Here it is 5:30 in the morning and  I miss to dring coffee....I will edit. Thanks

Comment: Then in my case if I use Kanthal A1 than it will be like  : R = 1.45 x 30 / A ... What is A ? CMIIW :)

Comment: Formula for area from diameter is??

Comment: In my calculation, R = 1.45 x 30 / ( 22/7 x 1 ) = 13.85Ω Why did it become 13,41Ω ? CMIIW :)

Comment: In here it's 11:19am... and I still did not sleep either... Out of coffee here... Lucky you... LoL... :P

Comment: @ Spehro Pefhany ..the usual one πxr^2....after the coffe!!

Comment: In my calculation, R = 1.45 x 30 / ( π x 0.5^2 ) = 55.4Ω or R = 1.45 x 30 / ( π x 0.512^2 ) = 52.8Ω ... How come it become 53.65Ω ? CMIIW

Comment: Diameter of AWG 18 is 1.016mm so r=0.508mm. Cross section area is 0.8107mm^2. Correct? 1,45x30/0,8107=53,65. Correct?

Comment: Ahh... a small difference for AWG18 between yours (1.016) and mine (1.024, with A=0.823) ~ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge

Comment: Which one is the correct one ?

Comment: Your reference is for copper magnet wire. I'm not sure if we can use for nichrome. I was find sizes from 1.00mm to 1.066mm for this AWG18 and for Ncr wires by varius manufacturers and for different alloys. Personally I using a table  like this one http://hotwirefoamcutterinfo.com/_NiChromeData_files/1_Amperage.jpg The dealling with heating elements is cut-and-try practice any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19947/discussion-between-sidhi-ciang-and-gr-tech).

Answer (score 2):

Easy to work this out from first principles.

The formula for power is \$P = \frac{ V^2}{R} \$ where V is the RMS voltage.

The formula for resistance is \$ R = \frac{\rho L}{A} \$

So, simply find the resistivity of [Kanthal A-1](http://kanthal.com/Global/Downloads/Materials%20in%20wire%20and%20strip%20form/Resistance%20heating%20wire%20and%20strip/S-KA026-B-ENG-2012-01.pdf) at 1400'C, the diameter of AWG 18 wire (1.024mm) will give you the cross-sectional area and work out the watts, using your given RMS voltage and wire length. Pay attention to the units.